# Should the [ts] tag be a synonym to [typescript]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Currently, the [ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ts) tag doesn't seem to exist. I believe that it should be a synonym for [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript). This makes sense given that [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) is a synonym for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py) is a synonym for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), and [cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpp) is a synonym for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). I believe that it would help improve consistency when searching the site, and I haven't found any posts that suggest that the tag could potentially be confused for anything else.

That being said, I'm far from what I'd consider to be an expert, so if there is any potential confusion that I've overlooked, I'd appreciate knowing about it. So in summary, are there any reasons why the synonym shouldn't be created?

Comment: "ts" is also used for other technologies. For example [transport stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) as well as [the Unix `ts` command line tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ts). I'm sure there are many others. Are there other alternatives to "js" or "py" which aren't JavaScript or Python, respectively?

Comment: @user18807217 isn't the point of having synonyms to make it so that you don't need to search through multiple tags? Am I misunderstanding what a synonym is?

Comment: Agreed. "ts" is fairly specific and is not really confused with anything else worth mentioning (in this context).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What for tags goes applies to synonyms as well.

Tags don't get created out of thin air, they can only come into existence when they get added to a question.

So first things first:

- Which question(s) would benefit from that tag; and
- Which expert would use that tag to find questions they can answer?

You would now argue: *All question tagged with typescript* to which I would respond: rather useless to have two tags that in no way divide a search result in any meaningful way.

The reason the tag [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) and its friends are synonyms can only be because they were deemed unclear, ambiguous and/or superfluous. We don't need to make the same mistake with [ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ts) first. Having [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) as only tag with no synonym to ts or other abbreviatons is fine.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the difference is between having [py] and [python] mean the same thing and what I'm asking for. If I search for "[py] some question" I get the same results as I would if I search for "[python] some question". What makes [ts] and [typescript] any different?

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge I would have been much more in favor of [py]  not existing at all, in which case your search would render results without selecting the python tag. Synonyms are meant to link questions that existed in one tag but are now better served under a different tag (think library rename etc). That your search use case works is due to history of those tags, not because we reckoned having them as synonyms in search would be awesome. As such we're not going open Pandora's box by now allowing adding synonyms just for the sake of search.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Are there any other options to help facilitate quick searching then?

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge yes, use an external search engine. I hear Duck Duck Go is worth a try. Those engines are way better at doing synonym, partial and soundex searches. Only use the SE search engine when you know what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean yes I am aware that search engines exist, and I use them frequently for searching for things. I just think it's a little sad that the most efficient way to find things on stack overflow is by not using stack overflow. Hence this post suggesting a small way to help improve that.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge There is no competing with the search algorithms that have been built into said external search engines, so it is very wise that the site owners don't even try. What would truly be sad is if you would rely on the limited site search and not find what a Google or a Duck Duck Go finds with ease. Use the right tool for the job. The site search is pretty much for finding things to answer since you can filter on unanswered questions and such.